# ndb query excluding multiple keys or ids

Tags: app-engine-ndb

I want to query for an entity but exclude a bunch of keys/ids that I do not want in the result. What is the best way of doing this?

I've thought perhaps the .IN operator would help me but couldn't figure out how.

So I came op with the following solution chaining single key exclusions:

```
q = models.Comment.query()
for exclude_key in list_of_comment_keys_to_exclude:
  q = q.filter( models.Comment.key != exclude_key )
q = q.order( models.Comment.key ) # without this: BadRequestError: The first sort property must be the same as the property to which the inequality filter is applied.
q = q.order( models.Comment.creationTime )
```

This seems to work but is it an ok way to go about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That might work but is rather inefficient. It will be cheaper to do the exclusion of individual keys in your user code, after getting all the results. E.g.:

```
q = models.Comment.query().order(...)
results = [res for res in q.fetch() if res.key not in list_of_comment_keys_to_exclude]
```